# Passing data from receiver to activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am really stuck. After test lots of different approaches. I'm asking this question.
I'm trying to make an app which should alert the users at the specific date and time, like lots of other apps that you have definitely seen before.  I'm using BroadcastReceiver as it should. I register it in manifest to activate it the first time the app gets installed and after restarting the phone but the problem is in android 3.1- taskkillers can kill this receiver so I thought it would be better to activate it again each time the app gets opened but The problem is that I don't know how many instance I'm creating so the first question is:

1. How to get the active receiver?

so I can make a decision upon it. If it is not active so I can active it again.
What I'm doing within onReceive is: getting data from database and comparing the time and date to now. If the app is not open I want to notify the user in notification area and pass extra data to the app' which is working pretty well. But if the app is open I do not want to notify the user in notification area, instead I want to pass data to an activity and alert the user in my app. I made my activity singleTask and used startActivity to pass data to the activity also I used onNewIntent method to handle new data but the problem is what if the user is using another activity.  The second and third questions are:

1. How to know if my app is open? (I used ActivityManager.getRunningTasks but I realized it is not a good solution because it is an api for Task Manger apps.)
2. how to pass data from receiver to my activity? (I used interface to pass data from fragment to activity so I thought it can be used here but it does not work here)

After a lot of exertion -Reading and Trying- I know i'm still doing wrong So please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you start a ServiceIntent from the Broadcast reciever. and from there you can send an intent that you can catch in the activity

Comment: Actually I'm trying this right now but the problem is I can call a method in the service from my activity but I want the opposite. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: You can use a few ways. you can put a broadcast receiver inside the activity and send broadcast from the service. you can use binder, you can also send pending intent and get it inside the activity onNewIntent. look in the documentation of IntentService

Answer (score 0):

Okay no one answered my question but I got it myself so here is my own answer:

1. Every receiver has only one instance and you can just enable or disable it. So to ensure that it is working you can enable it in your activity every time it gets run.
2. Within onReceive instead of doing stuff there, start a service and in your activity bind the activity with this service so in onBind and onUnbind method you can change a Boolean value and make decision upon it. In onBind make the value True which means your app is open and vice versa in onUnBind.
3. And finally the best way to pass data from service to activity is using Interface.

Now my app is working just like I want. . Hope to be helpful and save someone's time.